# I would like to order in SQL server where the first line is the same, but later it's different

Tags: sql, sql-server

The point in this case is that the starting point is the same for a line, let's say a train line. The line starts on the same point, but ends on different end points.
The services depends on the line where they are riding.

I've added the extra requested information, this could be extended with more lines.

Example table:

Initial situation:

```
Name    Next    Result
1000    1100    1
1100    1200    2
1100    2000    2
1200    1300    3
2000    3000    3
3000    4000    4
1300    1400    4
1400    1500    5
4000    5000    5
```

Expected result:

```
Name    Next    Result
1000    1100    1
1100    1200    2
1200    1300    3
1300    1400    4
1400    1500    5
1000    1100    1
1100    2000    2
2000    3000    3
3000    4000    4
4000    5000    5
```

If one extra row is added to the example input, the output would change as follows...

Example table:

Initial situation:

```
Name    Next    Result
1000    1100    1
1100    1200    2
1100    2000    2
1200    1300    3
2000    3000    3
3000    4000    4
1300    1400    4
1400    1500    5
4000    5000    5
4000    4100    5  -- Additional single row
```

Expected result:

```
Name    Next    Result
1000    1100    1
1100    1200    2
1200    1300    3
1300    1400    4
1400    1500    5
1000    1100    1
1100    2000    2
2000    3000    3
3000    4000    4
4000    5000    5
1000    1100    1  -- Everything from here is additional, caused by the one additional input row
1100    2000    2
2000    3000    3
3000    4000    4
4000    4100    5
```

Comment: Please, post sample data as text.

Comment: For your sample input: In the image the line `1000, 1100, 1` appears twice.  In the text it appears onces.  Which is correct?  (If it appears twice, you probably have issues)

Comment: I've removed the pictures. The current text is the correct information .

Comment: You appear to have a tree structure, and want to enumerate ever possible root through that tree.  Would it be possible to have the same source data but with an extra row `4000, 4100, 5`?  If so, please could you add that to your question so as to show how the expected results would change?  (Keep the existing example too.)

Comment: (If you add that extra detail, I'm prepared to re-open the question, as if I am correct in my assumptions I also believe I have an answer.)

Comment: @gordonlinoff : Additional information has been added.  The op just wishes to enumerate every path through an adjacency list.

Comment: @marc_s : Additional information has been added.  The op just wishes to enumerate every path through an adjacency list.

Comment: Well, until there are more votes to re-open, I can't provide an answer.  But, look in to recursive common table expressions.  That will get you started.  *(I'm sorry this was closed, I feel it was **extremely** harsh and unconstructive, especially as you quickly responded to requests for additional information.  I'm actually ashamed by the behaviour of such well respected members of the community.)*

Comment: This was my first question, and the way of adding tables/ pictures/ editing was not fully clear. Probably they have seen many newbee questions like this.....

Comment: The question is open again, and I've submitted an answer.  Please feel free to upvote any answer you get that are helpful, and accept the one that helps most/best.  Welcome to using Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be describing a tree structure...

```
           /- 1200 - 1300 - 1400
1000 - 1100
           \- 2000 - 3000 - 4000
```

The results would then be both (all) paths from the root node.

```
WITH
  leaf AS
(
  SELECT *
    FROM nodes
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM nodes AS lookup
                      WHERE lookup.name = nodes.next
                    )
),
  recursed_path AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    next AS branch_name,
    0    AS level
  FROM
    leaf

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    root.*,
    leaf.branch_name,
    level + 1
  FROM
    recursed_path  AS leaf
  INNER JOIN
    nodes          AS root
      ON root.next = leaf.name
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  recursed_path
ORDER BY
  branch_name,
  level DESC
```

***EDIT:***

Minor corrections made, and this link to a working demo...

- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f027656a4a7fb2e1f19e7395762c75aa

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! Just tested, this works on the normal lines like in my example.

I have to extend this, I've also have lines with the same start and end point, but via another route.

Comment: @Osmantugran - I can see the problem there, this code assume the end point is always unique.  There are alternatives, but I'm drowning at work, so likely won't look at it for a few days.  One alternative is just to (omg, I can't believe I'm saying this) build up strings of each route, so you end up with three strings of 5 values each, instead of 3x5 values in a certain order?